# How to automate the delegation of __special_methods__ in Python?

Tags: python

Let `spam` be an instance of some class `Spam`, and suppose that `spam.ham` is an object of some built-in type, say `dict`.  Even though `Spam` is not a subclass of `dict`, I would like its instances to have the same API as a regular `dict` (i.e. the same methods with the same signatures), but I want to avoid typing out a bazillion boilerplate methods of the form:

```
    def apimethod(self, this, that):
        return self.ham.apimethod(this, that)
```

I tried the following:

```
class Spam(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.ham = dict()

    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        return getattr(self.ham, attr)
```

...but it works for "regular" methods, like `keys` and `items`, but not for *special methods*, like `__setitem__`, `__getitem__`, and `__len__`:

```
>>> spam = Spam()
>>> spam.keys()
[]
>>> spam['eggs'] = 42
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'Spam' object does not support item assignment
>>> spam.ham['eggs'] = 42
>>> foo.items()
[('eggs', 42)]
>>> spam['eggs']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'Spam' object is not subscritable
>>> len(spam)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'Spam' object has no len()
```

All the special methods I tried produced similar errors.

> How can I automate the definition of *special methods* (so that they get referred to the delegate)?

Clarification: I'm not necessarily looking for solutions that leverage the standard method lookup sequence.  My goal here is to minimize boilerplate code.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm sure you have a good reason, but could you explain please why you don't want to make `Spam` be a subclass of `dict`?

Comment: Urgh. Second Zack: if you want to look like a `dict` then inherit from `dict`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This may not be helpful if you need a solution that prohibits metaclasses as well, but here is the solution I came up with:

```
def _wrapper(func):
    def _wrapped(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return getattr(self.ham, func)(*args, **kwargs)
    return _wrapped

class DictMeta(type):
    def __new__(cls, name, bases, dct):
        default_attrs = dir(object)
        for attr in dir(dict):
            if attr not in default_attrs:
                dct[attr] = _wrapper(attr)
        return type.__new__(cls, name, bases, dct)

class Spam(object):
    __metaclass__ = DictMeta
    def __init__(self):
        self.ham = dict()
```

Seems to do what you're looking for:

```
>>> spam = Spam()
>>> spam['eggs'] = 42
>>> spam.items()
[('eggs', 42)]
>>> len(spam)
1
>>> spam.ham
{'eggs': 42}
```

If on Python 3.x use `class Spam(object, metaclass=DictMeta)` and remove the `__metaclass__` line from the body of `Spam`.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a job for ... a metaclass!

```
def make_method(p, m):
    def method(self, *a, **k):
        return getattr(getattr(self, p),m)(*a, **k)
    return method

class Proxier(type):
    def __new__(cls, name, bases, dict):
        objs = dict.get('proxyobjs', [])
        if objs:
            old_init = dict.get('__init__', lambda self: None)
            def new_init(self, *a, **k):
                for (n,v) in objs.iteritems():
                    setattr(self, n, v())
                old_init(self, *a, **k)
            dict['__init__'] = new_init
            meths = dict.get('proxymethods', {})
            for (proxyname, methnames) in meths.iteritems():
                for methname in methnames:                
                    dict[methname] = make_method(proxyname, methname)
        return super(Proxier, cls).__new__(cls, name, bases, dict)


class Spam(object):
    __metaclass__ = Proxier
    proxyobjs = {'ham': dict,
                 'eggs': list,
                 }
    proxymethods = {'ham': ('__setitem__', '__getitem__', '__delitem__'),
                    'eggs': ('__contains__', 'append')
                    }
```

It works!

```
In [28]: s = Spam()

In [29]: s[4] = 'hi'

In [30]: s.append(3)

In [31]: 3 in s
Out[31]: True

In [32]: 4 in s
Out[32]: False

In [33]: s[4]
Out[33]: 'hi'
```

Note that you have to specify what parts of the interface you're using (otherwise, why not just inherit?). So we have `__contains__` from `list`, and `__getitem__` from `dict`, and the `__iter__` from neither. (And only one way to mutate the underlying list, using `append` but not `extend` or `__delitem__`.) So (like Martian) I'm not sure how useful this will be.

Answer (score 1):

Attribute access for special methods doesn't obey normal attribute access rules, basically those methods MUST exist at class level, read http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#special-method-lookup-for-new-style-classes

So you need to add all those methods either manually or you can add them to class programmatically and best way to do that is thru metaclass. Also note that I am not adding all  methods in `dict` but only special methods because rest can be easily redirected thru `__getattr__`

```
def redirect(methodname):
    def _redirect(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print "redirecting",methodname
        method = getattr(self.ham, methodname) 
        return method(*args, **kwargs)

    return _redirect

class DictRedirect(object):
    def __new__(cls, name, bases, attrs):

        # re-create all special methods from dict
        dict_attr_names = set(dir(dict))
        common_names = set(dir(cls))
        for methodname in dict_attr_names-common_names:
            if not methodname.startswith('__'):
                continue
            attrs[methodname] = redirect(methodname)
        return type(name, bases, attrs)

class Spam(object):
    __metaclass__ = DictRedirect

    def __init__(self):
        self.ham = dict()

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        return getattr(self.ham, name)

spam = Spam()
spam['eggs'] = 'yolk'
print 'keys =',spam.keys()
print spam['eggs']
```

output:

```
redirecting __setitem__
keys = ['eggs']
redirecting __getitem__
yolk
```

Disclaimer: IMO this is too much magic and should be avoided except for having fun :)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure `__getattribute__` will help, but the reason is the special methods are looked up in the class not in the instance: http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#special-method-lookup-for-new-style-classes , as for example the special methods like `__getattr__` and `__getattribute__` themselves have to be looked up somewhere.

Proxying like this seems asking for trouble to me without careful thinking, for example how should things like `__dict__` and `__class__` behave and about possible method conflicts if your wrapper happens to have any methods, and sure there are other problems.

Re: is-a vs. has-a:

If you just duplicate whole interface of contained member, it seems like anti-pattern to me, as that's what inheritance is for. What if you have a two has-a relations to two dict objects?

In has-a relation, one usually picks useful methods often exporting them under different names to make sensible API. So instead `Spam.append(item)` you would have `Spam.addBot(bot)`.